# Validation of optional attributes against xsd-schema in powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, xsd

I need to validate xml against xsd by powershell script with warnings about optional attributes, etc. 
For example, My xsd:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">


  <xs:complexType name="LocalizedValue">
    <xs:attribute name="Lang" type="xs:string" use="required">
      <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>Language Code</xs:documentation>
      </xs:annotation>
    </xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string" use="required">
      <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>District Typr</xs:documentation>
      </xs:annotation>
    </xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="ShortName" type="xs:string" use="optional">
      <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>Аbbreviation</xs:documentation>
      </xs:annotation>
    </xs:attribute>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="DistrictType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Localizations" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Localization" type="LocalizedValue"  minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
              <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>Local attributes</xs:documentation>
              </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Branches">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Branch" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:attribute name="Code" type="xs:int" use="required">
                  <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>Branch Code</xs:documentation>
                  </xs:annotation>
                </xs:attribute>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="Code" type="xs:int" use="required">
      <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>Dictionary code</xs:documentation>
      </xs:annotation>
    </xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="GroupCode" type="xs:int" use="optional">
      <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>Another Code</xs:documentation>
      </xs:annotation>
    </xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="IsDeleted" type="xs:boolean" use="optional" default="false">
      <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>
         documentation
        </xs:documentation>
      </xs:annotation>
    </xs:attribute>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:element name="DistrictType" type="DistrictType">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>documentation</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

And xml:

```
<DistrictType Code="1" IsDeleted="false" 
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./../Schema/flowGeoClassifier.DistrictType.xsd">
  <Localizations>
    <Localization Lang="ru" Name="район" ShortName="р-н" />
  </Localizations>
  <Branches>
    <Branch Code="1" />
  </Branches>
  <Countries>
    <Country Code="1" />
    <Country Code="483647" />
    <Country Code="2147483647" />
  </Countries>
</DistrictType>
```

I need to get some message like that:

*Warning: Optional attribute "GroupCode" is missing.*

I use a powershell script to validate:

```
$XmlFile = Get-Item($xmlFileName)
    # Perform the XSD Validation
    $readerSettings = New-Object -TypeName System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings
    $readerSettings.Schemas.Add($compiledSchema)
    $readerSettings.ValidationType = [System.Xml.ValidationType]::Schema
    $readerSettings.ValidationFlags = [System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidationFlags]::ProcessInlineSchema -bor [System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidationFlags]::ProcessSchemaLocation
    $readerSettings.add_ValidationEventHandler(
    {
        # Triggered each time an error is found in the XML file
        Write-Host $("ERROR line $($_.exception.LineNumber) position $($_.exception.LinePosition) in '$xmlFileName': " + $_.Message) -ForegroundColor Red
        $script:errorCount++
    });
    $reader = [System.Xml.XmlReader]::Create($XmlFile.FullName, $readerSettings)
    while ($reader.Read()) { }
    $reader.Close()
```

Has ValidationEventHandler validate optional attributes by standart methodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not create a variant of the schema in which the attributes are mandatory, and then validate against that?

Schemas are black-and-white, things are either valid or not: there's not really much room for warnings. But you don't have to use the same schema all the time, you can validate at different stages using schemas with different levels of strictness.

Answer (score 0):

The XmlReader considers a missing optional attribute perfectly valid, so will not raise an error (or a warning).

The only way to get this kind of information yourself is to check for them manually. You could do this fairly easily by reading your document into an XmlDocument and then [running XPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d271ytdx(v=vs.110).aspx) queries to check.

Comment: Thank's! But This method is not suitable to my case.